# 504 Gateway Time-out django mail

Tags: python, django, nginx

I use nginx. I get this error when I try to send an email. The SMTP data is completely correct.

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "123@yandex.ru"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "1234"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "123@yandex.ru"
```

send email

```
message = render_to_string('user/email_confirmation.html', context=context)
email = EmailMessage(
    '124',
    message,
    to=[user.email],
)
email.send()
```

On the other server, everything is exactly the same and everything works. But here there is an error.

Comment: Can you show us the full error traceback message?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about that( Running it on the local and it all works

Comment: Does the server have permission to talk to `smtp.yandex.ru`?